# Sending multiple values from php to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send 2 values from different parts of a page to the same ajax function. Basically, it's a search filter wherein selecting categories is one module and selecting brands is another both of which are attributes of a product and independent of each other.

I need 3 conditions where search is performed either

1. only if brand is selected or
2. only if cat is selected or
3. if both are selected.

My issue is `1 and 3 are working`. but `2nd condition isn't` as it takes the cat value as the brand. Please help me correct my function.

My AJAX function:

```
function filter(subid) {
  alert(subid);
  var brand_filter = new Array();
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
    brand_filter.push($(this).val());
    });
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getSubcategoryProducts.php',
    data: {
       brand_filter:brand_filter,
        subId: subid
    },
   success: function(data) {
    //alert(data);
    $('#productDetail').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    $('#sub_cat_menuItem a').addClass('.collection-category-brands li.active, .collection-category-brands li:hover');
    }
});
```

}

Module of selecting brand:

```
    <div class="collection-brands-filter">
                    <h4>Filter by Brands</h4>
                    <div class="brand-filter-form">
                        <form>
                            <?php $brandlist    =   $objBrands-> getAll("status=1");
                            foreach($brandlist as $branditem){
                            ?>
                            <span><input type="checkbox" name="brand_filter[]" <?php if ('checked="checked"'){ ?> onClick="filter(<?php echo $branditem['id'];?>);" <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $branditem['id'];?>"/><?php echo $branditem['name'];?></span>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Module of selecting category:

```
    <div class="collection-category-brands">
                    <ul>


                        <?php 
                        //Fetching sub categories of the main_category
                        while($query2res    =   mysql_fetch_array($query2)){ ?>
                        <li id="sub_cat_menuItem"><a href="#" onClick="filter(<?php echo $query2res['id'];?>);"><?php echo $query2res['1'];?></a></li>
                        <?php $subId    =   $query2res['id'];}?>

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

getSubcategoryProducts.php code:

```
    <?php 
    include_once("class/site_root.php");
    include('includes/connect.php');
    include_once(DIR_ROOT."class/functions.php");
    include_once(DIR_ROOT."class/products.php");
    $objProducts    =   new products();

     $subId =   $_POST['subId'];

    //IF ONLY BRAND IS SELECTED AND NOT SUB CATEGORY
   if(isset($_POST['brand_filter'])&&!isset($_POST['subId']))
   {
  echo "only brand is selected";
   foreach($_POST['brand_filter'] as $item)
{
     $res   =   $objProducts->getAll('status=1 and brand_id='.$item);?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($res as $val){?>

    <li>
            <img src="<?php echo $val['img_small']; ?>" alt="icon"/>
            <div class="collection-item-hover">
                <div class="collection-category-detail">
                    <a href="single-retail.php?id=<?php echo $val['id'];?>">Know More</a>
                    <div class="collection-item-detail">
                        <h4><?php echo $val['product_name']; ?></h4>
                       <p><?php echo $val['descr_small']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php }?>
     </ul>
   <?php }
    }

    //IF ONLY SUB CATEGORY IS CHOSEN!
    else if(isset($subId)&&!isset($_POST['brand_filter'])){
    echo "only sub cat selected!";
    $productsquery=mysql_query("SELECT products.product_name,products.id,products.main_id,
                        products.img_small,products.descr_small,sub_category.name 
                        FROM products 
                        LEFT JOIN sub_category on
                        products.sub_id=sub_category.id 
                        WHERE sub_category.id=".$subId);
      $count    =   mysql_num_rows($productsquery);

      $subNameVal=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select name from  sub_category where id=".$subId));

      ?>
     <h3><?php echo $subNameVal['name'];?></h3>
     <?php
    if($count>0)
    {
    ?>
  <ul>
    <?php 
  while($productsRes=mysql_fetch_array($productsquery))
      {
    ?>
         <li>
    <img src="<?php echo $productsRes['img_small']; ?>" alt="icon"/>
    <div class="collection-item-hover">
        <div class="collection-category-detail">
            <a href="single-retail.php?id=<?php echo $productsRes['id'];?>">Know More</a>
            <div class="collection-item-detail">
                <h4><?php echo $productsRes['product_name']; ?></h4>
               <p><?php echo $productsRes['descr_small']; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
<?php }
 ?>
</ul>
<?php }

}

//IF BOTH ARE SELECTED
else //if(isset($_POST['brand_filter'])&&isset($subId))
{
echo "both selected!";
echo 

"SUB-".$subId."<br/>";
          foreach ($_POST['brand_filter'] as $item)
           {
           echo "brand-".$item."<br/>";
           }
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: You should add the code of `getSubcategoryProducts.php`.

Comment: These codes seems fine.It depends on Your PHP code of getSubcategoryProducts.php

Comment: I have added them now! Please check!

Comment: you use an id for the li elements in the while loop. since an id has to be unqiue use a class instead `<li class="sub_cat_menuItem">` instead of `<li id="sub_cat_menuItem">`

Comment: My issue is when i select brand before selecting the category, sub id takes the value of brand! if i click on category after selecting brand, then it works!